# Using promise with redis callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, node-redis

I'm trying to populate my `var todos` with what I have in my Redis server, I get that I have to use promises but I'm probably not in the right place.

First of all, I get all ids with `.smembers()` function and for each of the id I'm getting the object with the correct id and parsing it into `todos`.

```
var todos=[];
res.locals.redis.smembers("todo:20", function(err, reply){ // i.e. SMEMBERS todo:20 returns 0 and 1
    var promises=reply.map(function(elem){

        res.locals.redis.get("todo:20:"+elem, function(err, reply1){ // i.e. GET todo:20:0
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                todos.push(JSON.parse(reply1));
                resolve();
            });
        });
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(){
        res.locals.redis.quit();
        res.render('todolist.ejs', {todo: todos});
    })
    .catch(function(reason){
        console.log(reason);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a promise not in the correct place. It must be created inside of `map` function, not inside of `redis.get` callback:

```
res.locals.redis.smembers("todo:20", function(err, reply) {
  var promises = reply.map(function(elem) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      res.locals.redis.get("todo:20:" + elem, function(err, reply1) {
        let todo = JSON.parse(reply1);
        resolve(todo);
      });
    });
  });

  Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(function(todos) {
      res.locals.redis.quit();
      res.render('todolist.ejs', { todo: todos });
    })
    .catch(function(reason){
      console.log(reason);
    });
});
```

But much better solution is to create a *promisify* function, and convert all callback-style functions to promisified functions:

```
let promisify = (fn, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(params, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
};

promisify(res.locals.redis.smembers, 'todo:20')
  .then(reply => {
    let promises = reply.map(elem => promisify(res.locals.redis.get, "todo:20:" + elem);
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(results => {
    let todos = results.map(item => JSON.parse(item));
    res.locals.redis.quit();
    res.render('todolist.ejs', { todo: todos });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Does this promisify function change the loading speed ? I get that it looks better, but I'm still confused why I'd be better than the previous answer

Comment: The answer is **no**, _promisify_  function doesn't affect the performance. As you see in example, it returns an object with simple logic: `reject` promise, when there is an error, or `resolve` with a result of async call otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert an async function that accepts a callback into a function that returns a promise, the general approach is to wrap the function in a promise and pass `resolve` provided by the `Promise` constructor as the callback:

```js
function getStuff(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb('stuff'), 1000);
}

function withPromise() {
  return new Promise(resolve => getStuff(resolve));
}

withPromise().then(console.log);
```

This means that, instead of putting the promise creation within your redis callback, you should move it outside of it:

```
res.locals.redis.get("todo:20:"+elem, function(err, reply1){ // i.e. GET todo:20:0
  return new Promise(...); // <-- move this outside of the callback
});
```

It would look something like

```
var promises = reply.map(function(elem){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    res.locals.redis.get("todo:20:"+elem, function(err, reply1) {
      todos.push(JSON.parse(reply1));
      resolve();
    });
  });
});
```